# Build C# SOAP web service stub based on WSDL XML SOAP response

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am doing integration testing of my system with a 3rd party web service.  They have provided the WSDL and the XML soap response packets but the web service hasn't been built yet.  I am using WCF to call the web service.

Any suggestions on how to write the end-point to send back the response contained in the XML file?

I know I can generate the service side from the WSDL but I'd like to verify the integration using the supplied XML packets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a more technical way, maybe using an interceptor to replace the soap response form your mock service, but a quick hack might be to just create the Mock service with SvcUtil, and grab your own SOAP response off the wire with fiddler or wireshark and compare the responses.

Answer (score -1):

I think SOAP UI serves your purpose. Using SOAP UI you can have a dynamic behavior to the service you want to mock. For example you might want to:

Read some data in a request and use its value to select which response to return

You can also virtualize the services multiple SOAP  request and response very well using ITKO/CA LISA.

LISA will record live service requests and responses, and create a virtual test bed to remove the team's dependency on live, connected systems or fully replicated test beds

You can also mock using concrete WSDL of target system using LISA

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering the OP's question. Specifically - how does your proposal answer: "Any suggestions on how to write the end-point to send back the response contained in the XML file?". Perhaps you could explain/elucidate?